# Is it possible to perform GUI testing using Xcode Unit test

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, user-interface

I would like to perform the following iPad/iPhone testing scenario automatically:

1. Tap Edit box A
2. Type text "abcd"
3. Verify button B is high-lightened

I understand UIAutomation 4.0 allow you to write a simple JavaScript to perform the above steps. However, UIAutomation does not have test infrastructure ready. For example it lacks testing macros to show if any tests failed and does not have a clear way to run setup and shutdown for each test cases.

That is why I look back to XCode unit testing. Logic tests won't work for me. How about Application tests?

Basically, I am looking for something that can do GUI testing and at the same time has test infrastructure. It is even better if it can be integrated to continuous build environment.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Zucchini](http://www.zucchiniframework.org/). It's just come out and I saw a demo at a recent YOW! conference. It's basically a BDD testing framework that uses coffeescript for scripting and runs against an actual device. It's also fully runnable from CI servers which makes it perfect for agile teams.

I haven't run it myself yet, but it seems to exactly what I'm looking for and No I don't work for PlayUp :-)